# Is there any possibility to add both Flurry and Crashlytics in my android app

Tags: android, flurry, crashlytics

I am using **flurry** in my android app, but flurry does not provide perfect crash report compare to **crashlytics** in my opinion. Is there any way to implement both in my app? I try to implementing crashlytics after implement flurry inside my app but it' not added to my app, crashlytics not launch my app if flurry is implemented in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me. I start it in the `onCreate` of the application using these lines:

```
    Crashlytics.start(this);
    Flurry.initialize(this);
```

I am using Crashlytics v1.1.10 and Flurry at v3.2.2